# Java OutputStream produces wrong directory path and characters

Tags: java, filenames, outputstream

i'm using OutputStream to create a pdf file for download as follow:

```
    byte[] infoFile = info.getBytes();
    String infoName = info.getFileName();
    String contentType = info.getContentType();
        
    response.setContentType(contentType);
    response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment;filename=\"" + infoName + "\"");
    response.setContentLength(infoFile.length);
        
    // till now no problem, the file name is ok

    OutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
    out.write(infoFile); 
    //here, as soon as the previous line is executed a file is generated with wrong characters
    // ex. D:__Profiles__User__Downloads__infoFile.pdf
```

Here the file produced is something like "D:__Profiles__User__Downloads__infoFile.pdf"
while i expect the file "D:\Profiles\User\Downloads\infoFile.pdf"

What's wrong?

Comment: What is the value of `infoName`? And "where" exactly is the name generated with wrong characters?

Comment: Java `OutputStream` doesn't produce directories at all, nor characters either. NB You don't need to set the `Content-length`.

Answer (score 2):

> What's wrong?

Your expectation that the filename in a Content-disposition header should have path information.

From [RFC 6266 section 4.3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6266#section-4.3)

> Recipients MUST NOT be able to write into any location other than
> one to which they are specifically entitled.  To illustrate the
> problem, consider the consequences of being able to overwrite
> well-known system locations (such as "/etc/passwd").  One strategy
> to achieve this is to never trust folder name information in the
> filename parameter, for instance by stripping all but the last
> path segment and only considering the actual filename (where 'path
> segments' are the components of the field value delimited by the
> path separator characters "" and "/").

And similarly in the [Mozilla docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition)

> The filename is always optional and must not be used blindly by the application: path information should be stripped, and conversion to the server file system rules should be done.

Basically you should only be specifying `infoFile.pdf`. It's up to the user which directory that file is saved in.

Comment: Indeed. It makes little sense to specify a full path when a file may be downloaded by something that doesn't have the same filesystem. Or, indeed, any filesystem.

Comment: @Jon Skeet: Thank you. Your comment is really informative. It helped me to understand certain things. Btw, my problem is that OutputStream creates wrong characters in the file name. This old code is not mine, i just intervened to fix this behaviour. I ended up changing on the fly the file name as follow: 
`code`
    String baseUrl = String newFilePath = FilenameUtils.getBaseName(infoName)
    + "." + FilenameUtils.getExtension(infoName );
    FilenameUtils.getPath(infoName);
`code`
Using this workaround the file is presented in the right way.

Comment: @AmiStack: It's important to note that your emphasis on `OutputStream` is misplaced. `OutputStream` itself is just an abstract class. It doesn't have any concept of files at all. It's the `getOutputStream()` method that would be deciding what concrete subclass of `OutputStream` to use, and how to configure it. (Unfortunately we don't even know the type of `response`, so it's hard to say any more than that.)

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. My mistake.